# Using lambda and defaultdict

Tags: python, lambda, defaultdict

I was reading about the collection defaultdict and came across these lines of code:

```
import collections
tree = lambda: collections.defaultdict(tree)
some_dict = tree()
some_dict['colours']['favourite'] = "yellow"
```

I understand that lamba takes a variable and performs some function on it. I've seen lambda being used like this:
    lambda x: x + 3
In the second line of code above, what variable is lambda taking and what function is it carrying out?

I also understand that defaultdict can take parameters such as int or list. In the second line, defaultdict takes the parameter tree which is a variable. What is the significance of that?

Comment: It does not take a parameter, it is simply a function taking no parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is roughly equivalent (ignoring metadata introduced by the `def` statement) to

```
import collections
def tree():
    return collections.defaultdict(tree)
some_dict = tree()
some_dict['colours']['favourite'] = "yellow"
```

The `lambda` expression simply defines a function of zero parameters, and the function is bound to the name `tree`.

Typically, you only use `lambda` expressions when you actually want an anonymous function, for example passing it as an argument to a another function, as in

```
sorted_list = sorted(some_list_of_tuples, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

It is considered better practice to use a `def` statement when you really want a named function.

---

`defaultdict` takes a callable to be used to produce a default value for a new key. `int()` returns 0, `list()` returns an empty list, and `tree()` returns a new `defaultdict`; all of them can be used as arguments to `defaultdict`. The recursive nature of defining `tree` to return a `defaultdict` using itself as the default-value generator means you can generate nested dicts to an arbitrary depth; each "leaf" dict is itself another `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 3):

> In the second line of code above, what variable is lambda taking and what function is it carrying out?

A lambda function is an *anonymous* (without name) function. So a lambda expression like:

```
tree = lambda: collections.defaultdict(tree)
```

is, except for some details (the fact that its `__name__` attribute contains the name of the function, and not `'<lambda>'`), it is equivalent to:

```
def tree():
    return collectsions.defaultdict(tree)
```

The difference with a simple exression is thus that we here encode the computation in a function. We can never call it, call it once, or multiple times.

It also allows us to *tie a knot*. Notice that we pass a reference to the function (lambda expression) in the result. We thus have a function that construct a `defaultdict` with as factory the function itself. We can thus recursively construct subtrees.

> I also understand that `defaultdict` can take parameters such as `int` or `list`. In the second line, `defaultdict` takes the parameter tree which is a variable. What is the significance of that?

The `tree` that we pass to the `defaultdict` is thus a reference to the lambda-expression we construct. It thus means that in case the `defaultdict` invokes the "*factory*". We get another `defaultdict` with as factory again the `tree`.

If we thus call `some_dict['foo']['bar']['qux']`. We thus have a `defaultdict` in a `defaultdict` in a `defaultdict`. All these `defaultdict`s have as factory the `tree` function. If we later construct extra children, these will again be a `defaultdict` with `tree` as constructor.

The `list` or `int` case is not special. If you invoke `list` (like `list()`), then you construct a *new* empty list. The same happens with `int`: if you call `int()`, you will obtain `0`. The fact that this is a reference to a class object is irrelevant: the `defaultdict` does not take this into account (it does not know what the factory is, it only invokes it with no parameters).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. So the code above allows you to create an infinitely nested dictionary by creating a new defaultdict each time you add a layer?

Comment: @Anya: yes, but you do not create that immediately of course. It is more that each time you get an item, like `some_dict[''foo']` and `foo` is missing, you invoke `tree`, which will thus construct again a `defaultdict` with `tree` as factory. But you can indeed walk arbitrary deep in this `some_dict`.